# Bootstrap render each page as tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created admin panel using bootstrap controls, lets take example as products module. So when the user click on product menu item it opens the products list, and when the user clicks on edit / details i wanted the product list page to stay as it is, but open the edit page as a new tab inside the same window. I have referred the image below, can you please let me know how to acheive this using bootsrap? I don't want to use bootstrap tabs and bootstrap tabs with Ajax, because for which I have to enter the code for listing and details in the same page, this will cause performance issue, instead the code will remain in different pages but just they will render as tabs in the same window, and user can switch between tabs and perform their actions.

[image: Product List Module]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such a user experience you want you must rely on AJAX or the new Fetch API,   otherwise you should send requests to the server, wait for server response and based on that render the desired page.

The UX you want to achieve is a SPA, Single Page Application,  which relies on AJAX calls to the server and modifies and/or shows the DOM based on both user requests and server responses.

You can use just one page,  and hide/show sections of it,  using navigation anchors #, and each section fetches data form the server.  Better than AJAX there is the new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API),  which improves old XmlHttpRequest.

I strongly recommend to fetch data from a RestFul API, that way each call is just an URL to an API endpoint which returns JSON formatted data,  light, safe, flexible.